# Chrome only error: Failed to execute 'scroll' on 'Window': No function was found that matched the signature provided

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I'm getting this error in Chrome only (it works in Safari/Firefox):
 `Failed to execute 'scroll' on 'Window': No function was found that matched the signature provided.`
The code is inside an inline event:

```
<div onclick='function scrollToByIntoView () {
    window.scroll({
      top: 0, 
      left: 0, 
      behavior: "smooth"
    })
  };
scrollToByIntoView();'>
```

I can't understand what's the problem.
PS: Note that this code is the output I get after DOM rendering. The actual code is splitter in different components/functions that I use in my server side templating engine, as, as noted in comments below, mixing this code directly should be avoided.

Comment: Mixing html and javascript should be avoided, mixing it like in the code you've shown is very bad.

Comment: I edited my question to explain the inline javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps try scrollTo. This is cross browser supported for x and y coordinates.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp

```
<div onclick="window.scrollTo(0,0)">...</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome. I have edited my answer to meet your requirement for a inline solution.

Comment: Should be `scrollTo` I guess. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo  w3schools link says the same

Answer (score 0):

`window.scroll` has no options, use `window.scrollTo`. See docs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo

and compare to

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll